# Can't get Winlogon automatic restart sign-on (ARSO) to work on a specific machine

Tags: windows, automation, event-log, auto-login

I'm trying to get [Windows ARSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/winlogon-automatic-restart-sign-on--arso-) to work on a machine but am unable to. (Windows 10 Pro 22H2)

It runs on other machines just fine, but not this specific machine. I've read through and double checked the two group policy settings (and associated registry entries) mentioned in the documentation. It doesn't matter if I do a regular restart or one via `shutdown /g`.

The referenced documentation states that the status of an autologon attempt is supposed to be recorded in the WinLogon event log. But the only entries on both machines where ARSO works and doesn't is `User Logon/Logoff Notification for Customer Experience Improvement Program`. And none of the reasons for ARSO failure in the Troubleshooting section of the doc apply.

Any thoughts on what I might try or be missing? Are there more detailed logs for autologon somewhere perhaps?

Comment: Check the enabling methods in [this article](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-auto-sign-in-and-lock-after-update-or-restart-in-windows-11.3324/). One of them might hint at the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the pointer. It was good to go through and read/check each of the settings compared to the problematic machine. Unfortunately everything was configured correctly but automatic sign-on still doesn't happen...

Comment: In case the user's profile got corrupted, try perhaps creating a new login profile on this computer.

Comment: Thanks, that was a great idea. No luck when I tried it sadly.